# Globalization in JQuery is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, globalization

I have been following the[Scott Hanselman Tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) on Globalized Javascript Validation. It is a great tutorial wich made me understand a topic I'm not that familiar with a bit better. The only problem is that it's a bit outdated because the link he provided to files like *jquery.glob.fr.js* is invalid. But you get redirected to the improved version by Jquery.

That's ok, but They just don't do what they promise to do. I tried searching for tutorials and information about this, but the only help on the internet is the ReadMe file. They state this =>

```
Globalize.culture( "fr" );
console.log( Globalize.culture().name ) // "fr"

Globalize.culture( "fr-FR" );
console.log( Globalize.culture().name ) // "fr-FR"
```

But when I try it my alertbox returns *en* instead of *nl-BE*

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/globalize.culture.nl.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/globalize.culture.nl-BE.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/modernizr-1.7.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/globalize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
@Html.MetaAcceptLanguage()
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Ask ASP.NET what culture we prefer, because we stuck it in a meta tag
        var data = $("meta[name='accept-language']").attr("content")
        //Tell jQuery to figure it out also on the client side.
        alert(data.toString());
        Globalize.culture("nl-BE");
        alert(Globalize.culture().name);
    });
</script>
```

At first I tried Globalize.culture(data), it didn't work so i tried nl-BE like the documentation states. No difference.

How do I get to change the culture to nl-BE instead of en?

Comment: The solution is placing the globalize.culture.nl-BE.js file underneath the globalize.js file. When you are desperate you start trying stupid things, and sometimes these things work...