# Jquery "$.preferCulture()" is not available/accessible

Tags: jquery, internationalization, locale, javascript

I have been trying to format regional (locale) specific numbers, dates etc using Jquery. Same things comes up in different tutorials on the internet. A code something as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" >

    $.preferCulture("de-DE"); //The method that causes culture specific formatting mainly
    var price = $.format("3899.359","c");
    $("#price").html(price);

    var available = $.format(new Date(2011,12,23),"D");
    $("#available").html(available);

    </script>
```

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx

I have downloaded the latest version of Jquery but I cannot find `$.preferCulture()` method in it. If I execute this code, I receive an error that this method is not supported.

I am using Globalize plugin for Jquery to get some more internationalization but even in that case, `Globalize.culture()` do exist but does not work. Say for example if I execute the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#btn1").click(function()
    {
        Globalize.culture("fr");

        var num = Globalize.format(123456.456789,"n3");
        //Globalize.culture("de-DE");
        //var num = Globalize.formatNumber("123456.456789","c");
        alert(num);
        alert(Globalize.culture().name);

    });

    });
    </script>
```

This displays an alert with "en" value instead of "fr" and number is formatted in "en" locale too. While using globalize.js plugin, I have also included globalize.cultures.js but in vain.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is your question?

Comment: 2nd comment in this link solves the problem. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750112/globalization-in-jquery-is-not-working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had similar problem lately and it turned out to be related to how I included culture file.

Be sure to actually import appropriate cultures either with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/culture.fr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/culture.de-DE.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/cultures.js"></script>
```

Please keep in mind, that it is really important what culture you are importing, for example when you want to want to format a value according to fr-FR, you should import cultures.fr-FR.js as it really makes a difference.
I also must point out that for formatting you should **always** include country information as formats tend to vary from country to country (even for the same language).

BTW. In current release, you also need to use precise culture for translating stuff (through `localize()`) as it want fall back. What a shame (but I will create a pull request with the fix, so stay tuned).

Comment: How small the problem was indeed. Thank you so much. Peace be upon you brother. =)