# Problems with JavaScript "parseInt()" decimal string

Tags: javascript

I get the total_amount in cart code of ecommerce web page, after I use toString function, but when I convert the 14.82 string to int number, the decimals   disappear.

```
<script>
 var total_amount_string = <?=json_encode($cart['total_pvp'])?>;//-> 14,82
 var total_amount_int = parseInt(total_amount_string).toFixed(2); //-> 14.00(here is the error)

console.log(total_amount_string) //-> 14,82
console.log(total_amount_int) //-> 14.00
</script>
```

What's the matter?

Comment: it is because of the `,` in `14,82`... what is the expected value...

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If the input string is `"14,82"` and you want the value `14.82`, you'll need to convert the `,` to a `.` and then use `parseFloat`:

```
var total_amount_int = parseFloat(
        total_amount_string.replace(/,/g, ".")
    ).toFixed(2);
```

`parseInt` will only parse the leading part of the string that defines a whole number ("int" = "integer" = "whole number"), so it stops at the `,`. `parseFloat` will parse a decimal number, but only understands `.` as the decimal point, not `,`, even in locales where `,` is the decimal point.

Answer (score 28):

you should use parseFloat() instead of parseInt(). Because integer number is not decimal.

Answer (score 4):

An integer has no decimal part, so any number "casted" to int will lose its decimals. You should use `parseFloat` if you want to keep the decimal part.
On the other hand, make sure you are not using a comma: [Javascript parse float is ignoring the decimals after my comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571553/javascript-parse-float-is-ignoring-the-decimals-after-my-comma)

Answer (score 0):

Your number is using a "," separator. Unfortunately there is no locale settings for number parsing in JavaScript, so you are forced to a bit more hacky:

```js
var total_amount_string = "14,823462";
var total_amount_float = parseFloat(total_amount_string.replace(",", ".")).toFixed(2);

document.getElementById("total_amount_string").innerText = total_amount_string;
document.getElementById("total_amount_float").innerText = total_amount_float;
```

```html
total_amount_string: <span id="total_amount_string"></span>
<br />
total_amount_float: <span id="total_amount_float"></span>
```

Answer (score -3):

The parseInt() function parses a string and returns an integer. ParseInt returns only the first number in the string is returned!. If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseInt() returns NaN.