# Output two digits after decimal separator that number containg comma also

Tags: jquery

i have a text-box that allow only numeric values,
and also it is separated with a comma, is working fine, while am using the decimal Separation it's clearing from the first comma field,

Example:
Am typing a number:43,553
i need the result :43,553.00
Now am getting result :43.00

please help me to solve this issue

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="form-control number numericOnly" />
```

scrip

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("input.number").blur(function () {
        $(this).val(parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
    });

    $('input.number').keyup(function(event) {

        // skip for arrow keys
        if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40){
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        $(this).val(function(index, value) {
            value = value.replace(/,/g,'');
            return numberWithCommas(value);
        });
    });

    function numberWithCommas(x) {
        var parts = x.toString().split(".");
        parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
        return parts.join(".");
    }
});

$('.numericOnly').keypress(function (event) {
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) &&
      ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) &&
        (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8))) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    var text = $(this).val();

    if ((text.indexOf('.') != -1) &&
      (text.substring(text.indexOf('.')).length > 2) &&
      (event.which != 0 && event.which != 8) &&
       ($(this)[0].selectionStart >= text.length - 2)) {
        event.preventDefault();
        }
       });
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0rxm9tt/)

Comment: **[This might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571553/javascript-parse-float-is-ignoring-the-decimals-after-my-comma)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of the `parseFloat` operation. The easiest solution is to replace the comma before casting to float:

```
$("input.number").blur(function () {
    $(this).val(numberWithCommas(parseFloat($(this).val().replace(/,/g, '')).toFixed(2)));
});
```

[Updated demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b0rxm9tt/4/)

Comment: it's allowing only one comma

Comment: try 7 digit number 1,234,564