# Javascript ParseFloat() usage with 9 digit

Tags: javascript

I want to convert string to float number but I have a problem

```
var b = parseFloat("10.525.142,25");
```

> "output = "10.525"

```
var b = parseFloat("10.525,25");
```

> "output = 10.525"

How I solution this?

Comment: "*I have a problem*" – Can you be more specific? Showing code that does what it is supposed to do is not a problem. Would you expect 10525142.25 instead?

Comment: Remove all the thousand separators using `.replace(/\./g, "")` and then replace the decimal separator with a `.` using `.replace(",", ".")`

Answer (score 0):

> If parseFloat encounters a character other than a plus sign (+),
>   minus sign (- U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS), numeral (0–9), decimal point (.),
>   or exponent (e or E), it returns the value up to that character,
>   ignoring the invalid character and characters following it.

```
parseFloat("10525142.25")
```

> 10525142.25

```
parseFloat("10525.25")
```

> 10525.25

[parseFloat specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1.2.3)

Answer (score 0):

To complete the previous answers and apply them to your problem.
Remove dots from your string, then replace the comma with a dot.

```
// Your string values
var strA = "10.525.142,25";
var strB = "10.525,25";

function fromUSFormatToStandard(x) {
    return x.replace(/\./g, "").replace(',', '.');
}

var a = parseFloat(fromUSFormatToStandard(strA)); // Output : 10525142.25 (float)
var b = parseFloat(fromUSFormatToStandard(strB)); // Output : 10525.25 (float)
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/jm3fr9d4/

Comment: it show 10525142.25 (float) but I want to show 10.525.142,25

Comment: I solve your first problem about converting string to float. 
You can now use "toLocalString" function and force the location.
Example : `x.toLocaleString("de-DE")`


https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

Answer (score -2):

The parseFloat() function parses a string and returns a floating point number.

This function determines if the first character in the specified string is a number. If it is, it parses the string until it reaches the end of the number, and returns the number as a number, not as a string.

Note: Only the first number in the string is returned,Leading and trailing spaces are allowed,If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat() returns NaN.

Content reference :

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp

You can check this post for why its ignoring characters after comma.

[Javascript parse float is ignoring the decimals after my comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571553/javascript-parse-float-is-ignoring-the-decimals-after-my-comma)

Comment: Answer copied from [here](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/error-make-sure-your-if-else-if-else-statement-returns-a-string-when-the-function-input-isnt-a-number/74079/4) without giving any attribution.

Comment: There is a difference between the answer and the help content in the above section , The answer has been linked as a reference , while the help content was refered from W3 , Not from any other answer as you have mentioned . Any way i have updated the reference of the content also.

Comment: It does not matter where you copied it from. *Always* provide the source.