# total basket reactive vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to make the total reactive? for example, in my basket I have two articles for a price of 18 €, if I add an article I want the total to change without updating the page.
my property calculate total returns me for two options:  14,0012,00  I would have liked it to calculate the price of the two options dynamically: 14,00 + 12,00 = 26

thank you for help

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div >
        
          <div >
            <u>
                <li v-for="item in shop" :key="item.id">
                    {{ item.label}} : {{ item.cost }}€
                </li>
            </u>
            <button @click="addItem">Add</button>
        </div>
       
        <div >
            <u>
                <li v-for="item in shop" :key="item.id">
                    {{ item.label}} : {{ item.cost }}€
                </li>
            </u>
            
        </div>
            <p>{{ total}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  computed:{
      totalbasket(){
            let total = 0
             this.shop.forEach(item=>{
                total += item.cost
                
            })
             
            return total
        }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is your `item.cost` is a string, not a float.
Parsing the cost to floats before adding them might do the trick:

```js
 totalbasket(){
   let total = 0
   this.shop.forEach(item=>{
     total += parseFloat(item.cost)
   })
   return total
   }
```

And at the moment you have `{{total}}` in your template. You probably want to change this to `{{totalBasket}}`.

As mentioned by [tony19](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6277151/tony19) javascripts `parseFloat` function does not recognize commas as decimal points. There's a question about how to solve it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571553/javascript-parse-float-is-ignoring-the-decimals-after-my-comma).

Comment: `item.cost` would need to be normalized before given to `parseFloat()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an Add Button to each item you want to add and then call `addItem(item)`. It would be something like this:

```
...
<li v-for="item in shop" :key="item.id">
  {{ item.label}} : {{ item.cost }}€
  <button @click="addItem(item)">Add</button>
</li>
```

Then, the addItem method adds the item, which would trigger totalbasket:

```
methods: {
  addItem(item) {
    this.shop.push(item)
  },
...
}
```

And in your template, you should print `totalbasket` instead of `total`:

```
<p>{{ totalbasket }}</p>
```

This should do it.