# JS inserting the points in the values ​and removing the ones that have

Tags: javascript

I inserted this code here in a module

```
function execute_foreach(array){
    array.forEach(element => {
       let valor = parseInt(element.innerText);
       element.innerText = valor.toLocaleString('pt-BR')
    })
}
```

I put to insert the point automatically in the values. But if I enter a point value of "3,000", its return will be "3". How do I solve this? I have researched and don't find it.
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: `parseInt()` is for integers. Use `parseFloat()` for numbers with decimals. And see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571553/javascript-parse-float-is-ignoring-the-decimals-after-my-comma for converting the comma to a decimal point.

Comment: This doesn't solve it, I don't even know why I put that parseInt

Comment: What doesn't solve it? `valor = parseFloat(element.innerText.replace(',', '.'))` doesn't work?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `3.000` or `3000`?

Comment: Use `.replace(/,/g, '')` if you just want to remove the commas.

Comment: Parsing back numbers formatted as human-readable for some locale is tricky, and more trouble than it’s worth if you have an alternative – for example, a `data-value` attribute with no thousands/other separators (and a `.` as a decimal point, if applicable). Then you can parse that with `Number(element.getAttribute('data-value'))`.