# How to make a number from string with comma separators in JavaScript ("23,21" ---> 23,21)

Tags: javascript, parsing, numbers, decimal-point

Does anyone know how to make a number from a string with comma separators, in JS.
I got: "23,21" and I want to get it as a number value.

"23,21" --> 23,21

Comment: That's not possible. A number has a dot as decimal separator. You can convert `"23,21"` --> `23.21` or `"23.21"` --> `23.21`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript parse float is ignoring the decimals after my comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571553/javascript-parse-float-is-ignoring-the-decimals-after-my-comma)

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

But before you need to replace comma for dot.

```
parseFloat('23,21'.replace(/,/, '.')); // == 23.21

let x = '16,5';
parseFloat(x.replace(/,/, '.')); // == 16.5
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/02tjm3vs/

Comment: This code converts `"23,21"` --> `23.21`. That's not the question.

Comment: @jabaa you're right, my bad. Fixed it.

Comment: You can't fix it. It's not possible

Comment: It's literally the solution you proposed in the comments and Tomasz approved it solved his issue.

Comment: My answer in the comments is: _"That's not possible. A number has a dot as decimal separator."_

Answer (score 0):

You can but not with the "comma" (,). In some countries people do use commas instead of dots to write decimals. If that's the case then what you can do is:

```
let a = "23,25";
let b = a.replaceAll(',', '.');
console.log(parseFloat(b));
```

But doing the this with the comma is also not wrong. But you will only get the part before the decimal.

i.e. 23 in your case

Answer (score 0):

Check if you want this.

```
var str = '23,21';
console.log((str.split(",").map((i) => Number(i))));
```

**UPDATE**

```
 var str = '23,21';
 var arr = str.split(",").map((i) => Number(i));
 console.log(parseFloat(arr.join('.')));
```

Comment: The question asks how to convert `"23,21"` to the number `23.21`. This converts it to an array `[23, 21]`.

Comment: @DonaldDuck I have updated my answer. Check if you need this.